# What is the difference between the two uses of generics (covariance)

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I think I understand that generics do not support covariance which is why the first example does not work and give an Invalid Cast exception. Everything compiles though.

But why does the second example work ? I can only see it to be the same thing.

*MyClass* is like this:

```
public interface IGenericClass<T> { }
public class MyClass : IGenericClass<SomeType>
{
}
```

**Not Working:**

```
public class SendingEmail<T>
{
    IGenericClass<T> abc;
    public void Send(IGenericClass<T> _abc)
    {
        this.abc = _abc;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
SendingEmail<MyClass> sendingEmail = new SendingEmail<MyClass>();
sendingEmail.Send(IGenericClass<MyClass>myClass);
//sendingEmail.Send(myClass); This was wrong
```

Also tried:

*Removed as it never compiled*

---

**Working:**

```
class SendingEmail
{
    void Send<T>(MyGenericClass<T> abc)
    {

    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
SendingEmail sendingEmail = new SendingEmail();
sendingEmail.Send(myclass);
```

Comment: Your non-working example should be `SendingEmail<SomeType> sendingEmail = new SendingEmail<SomeType>();` - not `myclass`. Your working example works correctly because it's inferring `T` correctly - that is, it assigns `T -> SomeType` rather than your explicit `T -> myclass`

Comment: Generics support *safe covariance* on *interfaces and delegates* when they are *parameterized with reference types*.

Comment: _"Everything compiles though"_ -- I don't see how. C# type safety should have prevented an expression like those in your non-working examples from compiling successfully, with an error on the `sendingEmail.Send(myClass)` call. I agree with the comments about you confusing which type parameters are which, but your question fundamentally does not seem to make sense either, as it has contradictory information in it. If you aren't able to fix the problem using the comments and answers given so far, fix the question so it includes a good [mcve] that does what you say it does.

Comment: You are right, this never compiled. I added a cast and removed the "Also Tried" part as it could not compile. I guess I got confused. Sorry about that. What are your thoughts on the edit I made ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example has nothing to do with covariance. You are simple confusing what `T` really is; `T` is `SomeType`, its not `MyClass`.

In the second example you are letting the compiler infer the type correctly and thats why it works.

**Edit**

The edit to your question doesn't solve the issue, you are still confusing what `T` is: in `MyClass` `T` is `SomeType`. In `SendingEmail<T>` `T` Should *also* be `SomeType` because `abc` is typed `IGenericType<T>` and you ultimately want it to be `IGenericType<SomeType>`.

In your code you are creating an instance typed `SendingEMail<MyClass>` which would mean that `abc` is really typed `IGenericType<MyClass>` which is wrong; You can not convert an `IGenericType<SomeType>` into a `IGenericType<IGenericType<SomeClass>>` which is what you are really doing when calling `sendingEMail(MyClass)`;

What you need to do is: `var sendingEmail = new SendingEmail<SomeType>()`.

About this being related to type variance, it is not. Type variance is what allows you to do `IEnumerable<Animal> animals = Enumerable.Emtpy<Tiger>()` for instance and disallows you to do the same with `IList<T>`; `IEnumerable` is covariant in `T` while `IList` is invariant in `T`.

Do note that C# does have broken covariance in arrays, the following is legal: `Animal[] animals = new Tiger[3]`. It's broken because now you can legally do `animals[0] = new Turtle();` and...ouch...you just got a runtime exception. This scenario is precisely the reason  why `IList` is invariant in `T`. Why C# has broken covariance in arrays? I dont know but I consider it an unfortunate (although probably justified) design decision.

Comment: I editied my answer and am wondering if your answer stays the same. Does the first example still have nothing to do with covariance ?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This is what I was looking for. I obviously knew there was something I was not getting but I did not know what. Isn't it what SO is for ? I can't understand why it was not received nicely. Thanks again